# Wordpress Theme Design is not changing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm facing a weird problem in wordpress. Every change I make in content and all others except "Theme Design" works great. Every change I make in "Theme Design" it takes almost endless time like when I first made change and then I keep trying on changing and saving different settings of Theme Design, it took almost 2 hours to show my change, same thing happened next time.

I'm using "venedor Green-pink" Theme.
This is my web on which I'm working on: http://www.teuscherchocolate-oc.com/

Background of header is transparent, I made this change 5 hours ago, now I've changed the background to grey color but the changing is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like a browser issue. When logged into wordpress you should see all changes, even to a simple stylesheet, etc.  However, outside of wordpress it could take an undefined amount of time for a browser to clear it's cache automatically for a new stylesheet it doesn't know is updated.

You could consider adding version numbers to the files responsible for your Theme Design changes. In other words, find what styles are being updatted and where. Tack on ?v=1 to the file.

If you clear your cache, do the changes show?